# Amor est adequatio rei intellectus- is this correct for 'Love is the equalizing of understanding'?

Tags: idiom

I would like to find a Latin sentence similar to 'Veritas est intellectus rei adequatio' but with Amor instead of Veritas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original quote from Thomas Aquinas (quoting an earlier philosopher) is:

> Veritas est adaequatio rei et intellectus.
>   *Truth is the equation of the thing and the understanding.*

In other words, a statement is true if it corresponds to a fact about reality.

If you just want to swap in *amor* for *veritas*, you get a grammatically correct sentence:

> Amor est adaequatio rei et intellectus.
>   *Love is the equation of the thing and the understanding.*

But I'm not sure this is what you want. Could you clarify the intended meaning? Do you want one understanding to be set equal to another, for example, or do you want to set the understanding equal to something else?

(I know requests for clarification are supposed to be comments, not answers, but this was too long for a comment.)

Comment: I would find a more standard translation of Aquinas: *equalizing* implies an active role, as if the two were made to be equal rather than found to be so. "Belief" is also not a good translation of *intellectus* ("intellect/understanding"; corresponding to Aristotle's νοῦς).

Comment: @brianpck Fair; isn't _**ad**aequatio_ somewhat active though, with the prefix? I normally think of _adaequo_ as "equalize".

Comment: I'd like to say 'Love equalizes understandings of itself' in a way which echoes Aquinas.

Comment: In certain contexts it can be active, but here Aquinas uses it as a synonym of *conformitas* and *correspondentia*. The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy has some good info on this in its article on the [Correspondence Theory of Truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-correspondence/). FWIW in that article (and in other translations of Aquinas I've seen), they translate *adaequatio* as "equation"; I've also seen the transliteration "adequation."

Comment: FWIW, I think Russell's famous example points up an inadequacy in Aquinas's definition: If the "understanding" is based on a mistake, maybe it would be better to use a different word, like "belief".  (If you think the prime minister's name starts with a "B", but you think Balfour rather than Boris Johnson is prime minister, that is a belief in something that is true, but you probably shouldn't call it "understanding", nor *intellectus*.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what the asker specified in the comments:

> I'd like to say 'Love equalizes understandings of itself' in a way which echoes Aquinas

This is diverging somewhat from Aquinas's idea, but if you want this specific meaning, I would say ***amor adaequat intellectūs suī***.